# What is a secure way to delete account in my application for users who signed up using their Google or Facebook accounts?

Tags: security, google-oauth, account

In my application users can sign up in 3 different ways:

-Using their email and a password

-Using their Google account

-Using their Facebook account

I ask for their password to the users who signed up using their email and a password, when they want to delete their account in my application, in order to provide a better security so that a person who finds my application opened in a shared computer can not delete that account if he does not know the user's password.

I want to know what would be the secure approach to follow when a user who signed up using a Google/Facebook account wants to delete his account.

Does OWASP have a guide about that?

Would it be secure to send that user a link with a token valid for one hour (same thing we do to reset password for a user who signed up using its email and a password when he forgets his password and wants to sign in)?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be concerned about an attack scenario where a malicious actor has control of the user's Google or FB account. There's no difference in attack surface and security posture of a "delete" function in your app between this scenario and the scenario where the attacker knows the email/password of a user who signed up directly with you. The probability of an attacker taking over a Google or FB account is a lot *lower* than the probability of taking over a user account on an *average* web app. (Your web app might be super secure and way above average..or not).

We would say your priorities should be reversed - doing a more thorough delete confirmation on users who signed up directly with you is a better idea.

Comment: The user may only have control of the user's app account but not of the user's Google account because the user could have signed in using his Google account but later could have closed the session in Google's account.

Comment: If they hijacked your app session but they don't have control of the Google or FB account, that's a different threat vector. Your suggestion of sending a link via email might work in this case but we haven't seen this in practice. Could the attacker change the email address in your app? Something to think about.

Comment: No, the attacker could not change they email address because otherwise he could change it to an address owned by him. What have you seen in practice to solve this threat vector (they hijacked the app session after signing in using Google or FB but they don't have control of the Google or FB account)?

Comment: If session hijack is a realistic vector, the best practice is to require additional authentication factor(s) on risky transactions. Example: if delete account is risky, then ask for one-time code sent to their email. This last example wouldn't work for Google/FB or even your "direct" users because the email account is not a distinct auth factor, they already used it to sign in and it's potentially compromised.